# getElementById with dynamic ID for onclick change images

Tags: javascript, html, razor, dynamic

I have id= image1 image2 image3 etc....and want to use one getElementById.
How Can I do this? What Can I put in xxxxxxx?

```
HTML:
<img id="image@(i.ToString)" onclick=diffImage(this) src="http://idratherbewriting.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/minusb.jpg" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo@(i.ToString)" /> 

JavaScript:
function diffImage(img) {
var image = document.getElementById(xxxxxxx);
if (image.src.match("http://idratherbewriting.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/minusb.jpg")) {
image.src = "http://idratherbewriting.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/plus3.jpg";
  } else {
 image.src = "http://idratherbewriting.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/minusb.jpg";
   }
}
```

Comment: You can put `"image1"` or `"image2"` or `"image3"`, etc. Or are you saying you want to get a reference to all this elements with a single function call? `getElementById` can always only return a single element.

Comment: getElementById(img.id) ????

Comment: Perhaps you could give them all the same name and use `getElementsByName` (or class and `getElementsByClassName`)?

Comment: getElementById(img.id)  works!!!!!!

Comment: Oh, now I understood the code and what you want to do. No need to use `getElementById` at all, just use `img` directly. It's already the DOM element you want.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want to change the image when clicking on it. Since you send `this` to function you don't need the `document.getElementById()`, you have the element in the parameter.

Try this:

```
function diffImage(image) {
    if (image.src.match("http://idratherbewriting.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/minusb.jpg")) {
        image.src = "http://idratherbewriting.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/plus3.jpg";
    } else {
        image.src = "http://idratherbewriting.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/minusb.jpg";
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have read the question better, the image is being passed in.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i=1; i < 5; i++) {
  var image = document.getElementById('image' + i);
}
```

Comment: defining var image outside for loop would be better...+1

Comment: when i click the pic i saw "0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'src': object is null or undefined"

Comment: @C-linkNepal I don't disagree with you, but if it's only going to be used inside the loop, I usually tend to declare them inside the block where they're being used. Yes, I know they get hoisted anyway, and yes I know that some prefer to declare all variables at the top of a function.